# How i can get ActionBarActivity from a Calss that extends from Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbaractivity

How i can get `ActionBarActivity` from a `Class` that `extends` from `Fragment` .

This is my class :

```
public class Email_Fragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBarActivity activity ;
        activity = this;

    }

    public Email_Fragment()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.email_fragment, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I need to this :

```
ActionBarActivity activity ;
activity = this;
```

And I need to use `clicklistener` .

Notice : I am using from `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a fragment you can call [getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()) to get the "parent" Activity. If your fragment always lives inside of an ActiobarActivity you can cast it as follows:

```
ActionBarActivity activity = (ActionBarActivity) getActivity();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get link to activity via    `getActivity()` and cast it.

Read https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

I guess, "Communicating with the Activity" will help for you.